# Reading data from a socket

Tags: c++, networking, sockets

I am having issues reading data from a socket.  Supposedly, there is a server socket that is waiting for clients to connect.  When I write a client to `connect()` to the server socket/port, it appears that I am connected.  But when I try to `read()` data that the server is supposedly writing on the socket, the `read()` function hangs until the server app is stopped.

Why would a read() call ever hang if the socket is connected?  I believe that I am not ever really connected to the socket/port but I can't prove it, b/c the connect() call did not return an error.  The read() call is not returning an error either, it is just never returning  at all.

Comment: Perhaps you have to send a message to the server before it will respond to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read is blocking until is receives some I/O (or an error).

Answer (score 2):

As John & Whirl mentioned, the problem is almost certainly that the server hasn't sent any data for your `read()` call to return. Another easy thing to overlook when you're starting out with network programming is that the data transfered in a server's `write()` call is not always symmetrical with a client's `read()` call. Where the server may `write("hello world")`, your `read()` could easily return `"hello world"`, `"hello wo"`, `"hel"`, or even just `"h"`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly changed your reader's socket to non-blocking mode, a call to read will do exactly what you say until there is data available: It will block forever until some data is actually read.

You can also use `netstat` (I use it with `-f inet`) to figure out connections that have been made and see the status of your socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is probably not writing data to the socket, so your reader just blocks waiting for data to appear on the socket.